# Can't run iex globally. A Mix error comes up

Tags: elixir, elixir-iex

I am very new to Elixir, and I am trying to run iex. When I type 'iex' in the command line, I get the following error:

```
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.0.5] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async->threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false] [dtrace]

** (Mix) "mix" with no arguments must be executed in a directory with a >mix.exs file

Usage: mix [task]

Examples:

    mix             - Invokes the default task (current: "mix run")
    mix new PATH    - Creates a new Elixir project at the given path
    mix help        - Lists all available tasks
    mix help TASK   - Prints documentation for a given task
```

I am currently using Elixir 1.5.1/Erlang 20

Why is Elixir requiring a mix.exs file just to run the shell?

Comment: Which OS are you using and how did you install Elixir?

Comment: Let me be a fortuneteller: you have an alias for `iex` that [likely] is set to `alias iex="mix -S iex"` :) Check your dotfiles (`alias | grep iex`). To run it immediately: bypass an alias by running `\iex` (note leading backslash.

Comment: That was it! Thank you!